# Truffle vs Web3

Tags: web3js, truffle

I have been learning Solidity and ethereum through some tutorials and so far it has been going great.

However, in the course the author uses solc (0.4.23) for compiling and web3 (1.0.0-beta.26) for deploying and interacting with the contracts. I am comfortable with this.

When I googled for some help for some query, everyone seems to use truffle for development and compiling etc. Also the syntax seems to be different significantly.

I am worried that which one to follow!! Can somebody please help?

Note:

I am comfortable with Javascript and NodeJS - in case if it might some give info to answer better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much different, Truffle is very helpful in many case since it gives you some function out of the box that you don't need to implement by your own (migration, deployment, compiling/linking)

The main difference is that Truffle is [still using web3 0.20.x](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/develop/package.json#L28) which is very different than web3 1.0, that's why the differences in the syntax.

You can choose which one to use basing on how comfortable you are with the tool, but consider that truffle is the most popular development framework for Ethereum.